# Set embedded array value OnInit()

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an encounter object which holds a Heroes[] and a Monsters[]. I'm using the in memory web api to get the data when this specific encounter is loaded:

```
getEncounter(): void{
const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
this.encounterService.getEncounter(id)
  .subscribe(encounter => this.encounter = encounter);
}
```

and this works fine. But I will have to make adjustments to the heroes and monsters properties and so I would like to load them into separate arrays when the encounter is loaded:

```
export class EncounterDetailComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() encounter: Encounter;
heroes: Hero[];
monsters: Monster[];  

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private encounterService: 
EncountersService, private location: Location) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.getEncounter();
this.heroes = this.encounter.heroes;
this.monsters = this.encounter.monsters;
}
```

But for some reason this is not working. Could someone explain to me why this is not working and how it can be resolved?

**EDIT**

Similar issue:

```
add(name: string, player: string, HP: string, AR: string, IM: string, imageUrl: string): void{
name = name.trim();
var hitPoints = +HP;
var armor = +AR;
var initModif = +IM;
if(!name){return;}
this.heroService.addHero({name, player, hitPoints, armor, initModif, imageUrl} as Hero)
 .subscribe(hero =>{ this.heroes.push(hero)});
```

}

This gives me the following [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KRKV.jpg) . But here I am using an observable.

Additional info:

```
<button (click)="add(heroName.value, heroPlayer.value, heroHitPoints.value, heroArmor.value,heroInitModif.value, heroImageUrl.value)">
Add new hero
</button>


 addHero(hero: Hero): Observable<Hero>{
this.messageService.add(`Heroes Service: added hero w/ name=${hero.name}`);
return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions).pipe(
  tap((hero: Hero) => this.log(`added hero w/ name=${hero.name}`)),
  catchError(this.handleError<Hero>('addHero'))
);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observables are async and you are trying to set values before your observable emits data (encounter) from your server.

Try this :

```
getEncounter(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.encounterService.getEncounter(id)
       .subscribe(encounter => {
           this.encounter = encounter;
           this.heroes = this.encounter.heroes;
           this.monsters = this.encounter.monsters;
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.getEncounter();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. I have another similar issue in my code, could it be that this is the same issue? I've edited my original post.

Comment: @Audiosleef I don't unterstand your next issue ^^ What's the problem ? Your list of heroes is not updated after you add one ?

Comment: Yes ! and the odd thing is, he creates the html list item but there is no data in it.

Comment: Hmm it seems right to me. Could you provide a stackblitz please ?

Comment: I need to see your template and more of your component :)

Comment: I was setting up my stackblitz, never used it before. But here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-heroes-issue

Comment: I found it. The problem comes from the id of an hero. If I post an hero with id property, data will be correclty displayed. I don't know what's your back-end stack, but your DB don't add ID automatically : >

Comment: I did this for testing and it works : `return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, { id: 56, ...hero}, httpOptions)`

You should check why your DB don't auto-increment primary ID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171674/discussion-between-adrien-saulnier-and-audiosleef).

Answer (score 1):

getEncounter() is async. You should return an Observable and wait for it to have a value emitted

```
getEncounter(): Observable<any>{
   const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
   return this.encounterService.getEncounter(id)
   .do(encounter => this.encounter = encounter);
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.getEncounter()
   .subscribe( () => {
      this.heroes = this.encounter.heroes;
      this.monsters = this.encounter.monsters;
   })
}
```

Comment: I used the code above verbatim and got the following error: Property 'do' does not exist on type 'Observable<Encounter>'.

Comment: Probably you are using rxjs > 5.5, as explained here https://medium.com/@gugui3z24/i-am-getting-the-following-error-property-do-does-not-exist-on-type-observable-any-79b381cac4b0 so you have to do the proper import of do operator

Comment: Indeed, i'm using 6.0.0. I tried the answer  Adrien posted and this works also so i'll stick with that. I have edited my original question with an additional issue, do you happen to know if this is the same issue?